# How can you quickly validate that a provided URL is valid?

Tags: java

I am writing a program where a user can input a URL but I need to check if it,s a real URL and not just some random string like `abcdefg.gggg`. I am thinking about pinging the URL. What is the fastest way of doing that in java?

I am thinking something like this but would be happy if you have a faster alternative:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
try {
    URL u = new URL(urlstring);
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
    int code = connection.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("" + code);
    if (code == 200) {
        ok = true;
    }
} catch (Exception error) {
    // error
}
```

Comment: Url should validate the snytax of the uri by its own, so you can't input *abcdefg.gggg*. If you do it (you can test it) you get an `URISyntaxException` or a `MalformedUrlException`

Comment: BTW: Do not catch the base class of Exceptions. Catch only special exceptions

Comment: Do you only want to know if the url is syntacticl vali or if this is existing and reachable?

Answer (score 2):

Any provided URL can be validated in multiple ways. The key points to be kept in mind are

- Valid Url Syntax
- Url connectivity exists

**a. Url Syntax validation**

1. The syntax can be validated by using [commons-validator](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-validator/commons-validator)

```
public boolean isValidURL(String url) throws MalformedURLException {
    UrlValidator urlValidator = new UrlValidator();
    return validator.isValid(url);
}
```

2. Using JDK to validate the url. As it tries to create the URL, but fails if its invalid.

```
Public boolean isValidURL(String url) throws MalformedURLException, URISyntaxException {
    try {
        new URL(url).toURI();
        return true;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e | URISyntaxException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

3. Using Regular Expression ( You should customize the expression as per your requirement)

```
    private static final String URL_REGEX =
            "^((((https?|ftps?|gopher|telnet|nntp)://)|(mailto:|news:))" +
            "(%[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}|[-()_.!~*';/?:@&=+$,A-Za-z0-9])+)" +
            "([).!';/?:,][[:blank:]])?$";
 
    private static final Pattern URL_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(URL_REGEX);
 
    public static boolean urlValidator(String url)
    {
        if (url == null) {
            return false;
        }
 
        Matcher matcher = URL_PATTERN.matcher(url);
        return matcher.matches();
    }
```

**b. Connectivity validation**

1. Using GET Request and validating response.

```
 public static String getStatus(String url) throws IOException {
 
        String result = "";
        try {
            URL urlObj = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            con.setConnectTimeout(3000);
            con.connect();
 
            int code = con.getResponseCode();
            if (code == 200) {
                result = "On";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            result = "Off";
        }
        return result;
    }
```

2. Using http HEAD  request method that is identical to GET except that it does not return the response body

```
URL url = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
```

3. Fetch IP Address of any url ( not recommended for ping validation as it has few issues)

```
InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(new URL(url).getHost());
```

Answer (score 0):

Check url is valid or not by  [Patterns](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Patterns#WEB_URL) built-in class

```
boolean isUrlValid = Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(urlstring).matches();
if (!isUrlValid) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid Url", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}
```

Comment: You are refering to android specific functions/classes. But OP does not nemtioned that he use android.